# How to change waitSeconds timeout before config in requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, requirejs

I am working on an application in which it is required to set `waitSeconds` to `0` before configuration(i.e. `requirejs.config()` ) gets loaded.

I don't want to set waitSeconds into requirejs library file.

Is there any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS can be configured any number of times. You could have

```
<script src="./path/to/require.js"></script>
<script>
  requirejs.config({ waitSeconds: 0 });
  requirejs(["main"]);
</script>
```

It is fine if `main` contains another call to `requirejs.config` (or `require.config`).

Or you could have:

```
<script>requirejs = { waitSeconds: 0 }</script>
<script src="./path/to/require.js" data-main="main"></script>
```

If `require` or `requirejs` is defined and has for value something else than a function before your load the script for RequireJS, then RequireJS will take it as its configuration.